# Good Ajax Chart/Graphic Library

Tags: javascript, charts

I know there has been several discussions on JavaScript chart/graphics libraries, and there is many out there. What I need is one that can:

1. Zooming and panning
2. Data point manipulation (like when click on a data point, highlight other data points within the data series with the same certain parameter of the clicked one)
3. Dynamically change data point values (e.g.: dragging a data point dynamically updating the line shape)
4. Error bar support, horizontally and vertically
5. Select data points on the chart
   Seems like Flot may have most of the features, if not all(not sure about 3, and 4), but would like to see if I don't miss out on there nice libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the awesome Visualization API on Google's [AJAX APIs Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://raphaeljs.com/ library.
It has a plugin called gRaphaël which is charting plugin.
Look good but personally didn't use it.
Good luck and share you expirience if you try it.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dojo](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dojox.charting) [Charting Engine](http://ajaxian.com/archives/dojo-charting-engine-released) has a pretty astonishing featureset. Sadly dojo seems to suffer from a general lack of evangelism. 
I dont know if there are good introductory tuts, maybe the best way is to learn from [examples](http://shaneosullivan.wordpress.com/2007/06/15/dojo-charting-example-to-show-website-statistics-2/).

Comment: thanks for your response, I'm currently using dojox charting, it's nice when you just need to plot the charts, but it doesn't have error bar support for a given data point, zoom/panning is here but not very straightforward, and don't have much control on individual data points, at least this is what I've found out.